# How to position checkbox on top of DIV while creating checkbox inside of foreach

Tags: jquery, css, arrays

This is my output

[image]

This is my .html

```
    <td class="category" colspan ="2" id="tdcategory1">
         <div id="category1" style="border:none !important; overflow:hidden; width:auto; height:auto">
         </div>
    </td>
```

my procdure is I will create checkbox inside of id="tdcategory1"
and I will create many checkbox inside of id="category1"

this is my .js

```
     var div = $('#tdcategory1');
     var input = $('<input />', { type: 'checkbox', name: "chkallcategory1", id: "chkallcategory1", value: 1, style: "cursor:pointer" });
     input.appendTo(div);

     $.each(data.Records, function (e, key, value) {
      var div = $('#category1');
           var input = $('<input />', { type: 'checkbox', name: cate_name, id: cate_name + '_' + key.id, value: key.id, style: "cursor:pointer" });
         input.appendTo(div);
     });
```

The problem is my first Checkbox created are position in the bottom of #category1 div

Comment: Because you are appending 'top' checkbox to TD but any following checkboxes to the former DIV inside this TD

Comment: try this `$('#category1').before(input)`;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are doing `appendTo` for first checkbox it will create below markup in your page:

```
<td class="category" colspan ="2" id="tdcategory1">
         <div id="category1" style="border:none !important; overflow:hidden; width:auto; height:auto">
         </div>
         <!-- checkbox here -->
</td>
```

So you should add it before div with id `category1`

**Method #1**

You should use `insertBefore` method like below:

```
var div = $('#category1');
var input = $('<input />', { type: 'checkbox', name: "chkallcategory1", id: "chkallcategory1", value: 1, style: "cursor:pointer" });
input.insertBefore(div);

$.each(data.Records, function (e, key, value) {
  var div = $('#category1');
  var input = $('<input />', { type: 'checkbox', name: cate_name, id: cate_name + '_' + key.id, value: key.id, style: "cursor:pointer" });
  input.appendTo(div);
});
```

**Method #2**

in case you do not have access to element and wants to add as a first you should use `prependTo` like below

```
var div = $('#tdcategory1');
var input = $('<input />', { type: 'checkbox', name: "chkallcategory1", id: "chkallcategory1", value: 1, style: "cursor:pointer" });
input.prependTo(div);

$.each(data.Records, function (e, key, value) {
  var div = $('#category1');
  var input = $('<input />', { type: 'checkbox', name: cate_name, id: cate_name + '_' + key.id, value: key.id, style: "cursor:pointer" });
  input.appendTo(div);
});
```

Comment: this one is great input.insertBefore(div); thank you for helping

Answer (score 2):

Use prependto() function.

```
var div = $('#tdcategory1');
 var input = $('<input />', { type: 'checkbox', name: "chkallcategory1", id: "chkallcategory1", value: 1, style: "cursor:pointer" });
 input.prependTo(div);
```

Check out [this link](http://api.jquery.com/prependTo/) for more information.